# Nestjs desctructuring

Tags: typescript, nestjs

It's two week since I'm trying to resolve this problem. It work on linux but not in windows and I don't know why. Do someone know how to resolve it ? Here is a screenshot of the error in my terminal.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRaMH.jpg)

Someone pls help me resolving this problem

Comment: Please, post your error message in the post, not a an image to another site.

Answer (score 0):

For me , i created a folder public/templates/nameFile.hbs
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpFN1.png

then i set template dir like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR8eS.png

Comment: It's working finally

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I use the same structure but in the template, I use process.cwd . I think it's because of windows OS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IWz3.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).